# Getting a cannot POST error even though I'm using "a _method=PUT" , I'm using Node.js Express MongoDB and Clouidnary

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web-applications, cloudinary

This is form action:

```
<form action="/index/<%= picture._id %>/?_method=PUT" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This is my Edit Route

```
app.put("/index/:id", upload.single('image'), function(req, res)
```

The error I'm getting':
Cannot POST /index/606ee3d76e310406f4111d90/

**Overview of my web app** :
I'm using Node.js, Express, MongoDB and Cloudinary.
My web app is like a photo gallery where a photographer can upload their photos.
I'm using cloudinary to store the photos with the help of multer and then I store the URL of the image from Cloudinary in MongoDB along with some other data.

**The Error :**
im getting a **"Cannot POST /index/606ee3d76e310406f4111d90/"** error when i try to edit the details of an existing photo or replace the photo itself and submit it in a form.
Here is my **EDIT Route** :

```
app.put("/index/:id", upload.single('image'), function(req, res){
 photoObject.findById(req.params.id, async function(err, foundPhoto){ //Find the photo object in MongoDB
    if(err){
        req.flash("error", err.message);
        res.redirect("back");
    } else {
          if (req.file) { // check to see if user uploads an image to replace the existing image
              try {
                  await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(foundPhoto.imageId); // delete the existing image from cloudinary
                  var result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path); // upload the new image which the user uploaded to cloudinary
                  foundPhoto.imageId = result.public_id; //in MongoDB, set the imageId to the public_id which is given by cloudinary
                  foundPhoto.image = result.secure_url; //in MongoDB, set the URL with secure_url which is given by cloudinary
              } catch(err) {
                  req.flash("error", err.message);
                  return res.redirect("back");
              }
          }
         // Handling of data changes if any
        foundPhoto.name = req.body.name || foundPhoto.name;
        foundPhoto.description = req.body.description || foundPhoto.description;
        foundPhoto.price = req.body.price || foundPhoto.price;
        foundPhoto.save(); // save the photo in MongoDB
        req.flash("success","Successfully Updated!");
        console.log("Successfully updated !");
        res.redirect("/index/" + foundPhoto._id); // Redirect to the show page
    }
});
```

});

**Here is my Edit.ejs**

```html
<%- include("partials/header") %>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align:center;">Edit <%= picture.name %></h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 50px auto">
            <form action="/index/<%= picture._id %>/?_method=PUT" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="<%= picture.name %>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="image">Image</label>
                                    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*" >
                                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price" value="<%= picture.price %>" min="0.01" step="0.01">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" value="<%= picture.description %>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block btn-primary">Submit!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/index">Go Back!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<%- include("partials/footer") %>
```

**Additional info :**

when I send a PUT request for https://webdev1-hithere.run-ap-south1.goorm.io/index/606ee3d76e310406f4111d90/ using postman, my app.put Route(which is given above) seems to be stuck in an infinite loop as the text "Successfully Updated!"(the second last line of my app.put Route) is repeatedly printed in my console but I send a POST request with this https://webdev1-hithere.run-ap-south1.goorm.io/index/606ee3d76e310406f4111d90/?_method=PUT, I get a Cannot POST error

Comment: Your code suggests that you should have a middleware that looks for a _method querystring parameter and changes the req.method for the current request accordingly. Do you actually have such a middleware in your stack?

Comment: Hey @IAmDranged, yes that was the problem. I forgot to require "method-override". Very sorry for this silly question.

Comment: Not a problem at all.